# std::norm(std::complex) uses square root instead of fast implementation

Tags: c++

in c++ the `norm` of a complex numer `c` is defined as `abs(c)^2` . this means its `re(c)^2+im(z)^2`.

this is the implementation:

```
template<bool>
struct _Norm_helper
{
  template<typename _Tp>
    static inline _Tp _S_do_it(const complex<_Tp>& __z)
    {
      const _Tp __x = __z.real();
      const _Tp __y = __z.imag();
      return __x * __x + __y * __y;
    }
};

template<>
struct _Norm_helper<true>
{
  template<typename _Tp>
    static inline _Tp _S_do_it(const complex<_Tp>& __z)
    {
      _Tp __res = std::abs(__z);
      return __res * __res;
    }
};
```

**why would anyone want to use the second implementation?**

the first one is clearly faster, because it doesnt use `abs`, where `sqrt` is involved.

Comment: `the first one is clearly faster`  Well, did you do timing tests to verify this claim?

Comment: The implementation is not set by the C++ standard. Which standard library are you looking at?

Comment: i found it in mingw, gcc 4.8.1, and i tested it with a standard mandelbrot.

Comment: I think there is a non-abs implementation for floating point types. Look for `_S_do_it`.

Comment: The C++ Standard requires [complex.value.ops] that it "*Returns:* The squared magnitude of `x`." So, generically, you'll have to use the second implementation, unless you can prove the first one will do the same. This of course dodges the question, which now is *why did they specify it in that way*?

Comment: that is exactly what ive meant to ask ;)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm definitely prepared to accept without testing that 'two multiplies and an add' is faster than a hypot followed by a multiply. hypot[f] (which is what abs(z) uses - must use ) is coded for accuracy and avoiding over/underflow, and this takes extra time well beyond the sqrt. However, all these mitigations are basically moot if you then square the result.

Comment: @dyp do you read that as implying that if the norm(z) and abs(z)*abs(z) are not identical, then norm() is non-compliant, even if the norm(z) is no less, or more, accurate? I would have thought that 'squared magnitude of x' would be interpreted in mathematical terms. Bear in mind that abs(z) uses hypot, which is *not* one of the functions that is specified to be perfectly compliant by IEEE754. So the first implementation also has the advantage of always giving the same result on different compliant FP platforms, whereas the second may not.

Comment: @greggo I think this is what I meant back then ;) `std::abs(complex<T> const& x)` is specified to return *the magnitude of `x`*, which can be read as *`std::abs(x)` is the magnitude of `x`*. But actually, the spec itself is not accurate enough to decide on this. The C programming language OTOH does specify in its IEC 60559 annex that `cabs(` *x + iy* `) = hypot(` *x, y* `)`. I cannot find any definition for some `norm` function, though.

Comment: Just checked stdlib 9 (gcc 9) and the `abs` implementation is commented: `//_Tp __res = std::abs(__z);
          //return __res * __res;
          const _Tp __x = __z.real();
          const _Tp __y = __z.imag();
          return __x * __x + __y * __y;`, Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we will look into the implementation, we will find the answer there,

```
  // 26.2.7/5: norm(__z) returns the squared magnitude of __z.
  //     As defined, norm() is -not- a norm is the common mathematical
  //     sens used in numerics.  The helper class _Norm_helper<> tries to
  //     distinguish between builtin floating point and the rest, so as
  //     to deliver an answer as close as possible to the real value.
  template<bool>
    struct _Norm_helper
    {
      template<typename _Tp>
        static inline _Tp _S_do_it(const complex<_Tp>& __z)
        {
          const _Tp __x = __z.real();
          const _Tp __y = __z.imag();
          return __x * __x + __y * __y;
        }
    };

  template<>
    struct _Norm_helper<true>
    {
      template<typename _Tp>
        static inline _Tp _S_do_it(const complex<_Tp>& __z)
        {
          _Tp __res = std::abs(__z);
          return __res * __res;
        }
    };

  template<typename _Tp>
    inline _Tp
    norm(const complex<_Tp>& __z)
    {
      return _Norm_helper<__is_floating<_Tp>::__value 
         && !_GLIBCXX_FAST_MATH>::_S_do_it(__z);
    }
```

So the second implementation is called when `norm` is applied to a value of a builtin floating-point type (which is `float`, `double`, `long double`, or `__float128` as per GCC 4.8.1) and if the `-fast-math` option is not set. This is done to conform with the standard definition where `norm` is defined as `the squared magnitude of z`.

Due to the rounding errors, `z.real()*z.real() + z.imag()*z.imag()` is not equal `abs(z)*abs(z)`, therefore the first version will be inconsistent with the specification wording (which probably indicates that there is a problem with the specification). To make it easier to understand, why the wording matters, consider the code that expects that `norm(x) / abs(x) = x`. Which is, of course, a bad code, but the standard in some sense guaranteed that this should be true.

However, once FAST_MATH is set or when `complex` is specialized to a non-builtin type, the standard doesn't have its power anymore (since it clearly says that the behavior is undefined) and the implementation is falling to the first implementation which is arguably<sup>1</sup> faster and more precise.

---

<sup>1)</sup>) it actually depends on many factors (like whether builtin intrinsics are used) and yada, yada, yada, so let's take this claim with a grain of salt.

Comment: Good point, but, std::complex<T> is fairly clearly defined to *not* be useful for T other than float, double, long double (and I may be wrong about the last one :-) ). Since the OP code only applies to complex<T>, there doesn't seem to be much point in making a provision here for a complex<USERT> and then having std::norm() work because std::abs() was supplied for that type.

Comment: Where is is defined to not be useful for other T? I can imagine lots of different implementations of real numbers, other than built-in

Comment: I can too, doesn't mean that std::complex will work for them :-) . If you trust this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex "The effect of instantiating the template complex for any other type [beyond float, double, long double] is unspecified"

Comment: This is a correct answer. It would be the perfect explanation if the generic (fallback) implementation were `using std::abs; _Tp __res = abs(__z);` or something like this. I don't think `std::abs` can be specialized/overloaded for your own types, and even if it were one might want to define `abs` in another namespace. Having said that, nowadays gcc (9) implements this consistently, without using the abs function.

Comment: @alfC, you probably meant that this is an _incorrect_ answer? I decided to look deeper five years later and dug into the implementation to find the (I believe) right answer.

Comment: I meant that is was mostly correct, except that it still did not explain why std::abs was used and not an ADL version. In any case the implementation changed and it is more generic now

Comment: Where does that definition of norm come from? In this context I find that confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the similar function `std::hypot` on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/), which says "Computes the square root of the sum of the squares of x and y, **without undue overflow or underflow at intermediate stages of the computation.**"

(*I'm guessing that `std::abs` is usually just a wrapper around `std::hypot`*).

This is the key: **it's all about numerical stability**. Consider the case y=0, and x>0 being either very large *or* very small, for the floating point representation.

Thus if x is very large, so that x^2 = +inf, then just doing sqrt(x^2 + y^2) would overflow and give +inf. If x is very small, so that x^2 = 0, you'd get 0.

(Always remembering that we're talking about *floating point representations*).

In either case, it is very different from the correct answer x.

The *correct* algorithm is: consider, e.g., the case x > y > 0. Let r = y/x and calculate instead x.sqrt( 1 + r^2), which is much better behaved numerically; notice that 0 < r < 1. In general you'd consider the larger of |x| and |y| and divide it out, taking care of when x,y are both zero.

Any good `std::abs` implementation which cares about accuracy rather than speed is doing something similar to above I bet, NOT doing sqrt(x^2 + y^2) at all.

You can do some simple numerical analysis (*if you know a bit of calculus and Taylor series, and/or the Binomial Expansion for power p=1/2*): some algebraic calculations to work out the likely sizes of the errors will show that the naive sqrt(x^2 + y^2) formula is more error prone.

Comment: I think you have a point, but the original question is about x^2+y^2, not the square root. So in your example with y=0 and x is so close to 0 that `x*x==0.0`, then `abs(z)*abs(z)`will also be `0.0` even if `abs(z)==x`, so there is no difference. However, if x and y are both small, it may be that `x*x+y*y` would give `0.0`, but `abs(z)` could be large enough that the square is non-zero.